# Reading data from scanned pdf

Tags: pdftotext

I have pdfs which are scanned and can not be converted to either text or even copy and paste as text in a text editor.

Is there a way I can convert such scanned PDF files in TEXT format either programmatically or manually ?

Thanks

Comment: any platform is fine, manually also fine, like we can copy and paste standard pdfs data or even use Acrobat's own convert to text.

Answer (score 2):

Since the document is scanned, you likely have only an image to work with. You may have some luck with Optical Character Recognition (or OCR). This method allows you to extract textual data from an image.

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is a popular engine, that I've used in my projects to much success. You may consider checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to convert the text manually and it is not 100,000 rows, you can always type all the data yourself or with team mates if you can find helpers for a tedious task. 
There are great OCR software tools available you can use to do this job. They've really come a long way.

If you want to do this programmatically, check out this guide from Dan Nguyen, formerly at ProPublica.

http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/doc-dollars-guides-collecting-the-data

He walks through how they did it through PDFs of scanned documents from doctors' offices. He used Ruby on Rails and has code samples you can see of how he pulled the data: http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/turning-pdfs-to-text-doc-dollars-guide

I believe some of ProPublica's code is available on github so you might want to fork their code there.